# Changes made to report in SSRS is not reflecting when exported to CSV but works fine with XLSX format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I had changed the font size of report data and also changed the headers to bold to the existing report in SSRS however after the changes when the report is export in XLSX format and PDF format , i am able to see the desired output but i cant see my changes in CSV format .
thanks in advance .

Comment: CSV file type saves only data not styles

Comment: CSV files contain Comma Separated Values which is just the data, so no formatting is exported. It is used for other programs to ingest the data not for humans to read. XLSX and PDF are meant for humans to read and so the formatting is exported along with the data.